# ImportError: cannot import name eigen_symmetric in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, pca

I copy and paste the PCA code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/pypca/source/browse/trunk/PCA.py?r=2).

However, I encounter the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name eigen_symmetric
```

**Why is this happenning and how to fix it?**

Comment: Which `scipy` version are you on?

Comment: http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/running-script-error-eigen-symmetric-td1464.html

Comment: @SukritKalra  how to check version thanks!

Comment: `import scipy; scipy.__version__`.

Comment: @SukritKalra   '0.11.0'

Comment: @perfectionm1ng : Posted an answer. This should get it done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eigen_symmetric` function has been renamed to `eigsh` in `Scipy 0.9.0`. You need to find and replace all occurences of `eigen_symmetric` with `eigsh`.

Comment: Another error on the final line return:
  File "<stdin>", line 72
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Hi! The script you pointed us at is not the complete one, you need to go to Downloads and download the .ZIP file and use PCA.py from there after replacing all occurrences of eigen_symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

please check whether you have add scipy library to root path

Comment: could you tell me how to check?